# Path Tcl and Bash

Tags: bash, tcl, ns2, otcl

i have a problem with path in a tcl file; I tried to use

```
source  " /tmp/mob.tcl "
```

and this path in bash file :

```
/opt/ns-allinone-2.35/ns-2.35/indep-utils/cmu-scen-gen/setdest/setdest -v 1 -n $n -p 10 -M 64 -t 100 -x 250 -y 250 >> /tmp/mob.tcl
```

but terminal give me this error :

```
couldn't read file " /tmp/mob.tcl ": no such file or directory
    while executing
"source.orig { /tmp/mob.tcl }"
```

someone can help me please

Answer (score 1):

Learn to believe the error messages you get ;-).

```
couldn't read file " /tmp/mob.tcl ": no such file or directory
```

This is because you have submitted a string with the first letter (and the last) of the path being a " " char, i.e.

```
            source  " /tmp/mob.tcl "
```

try submitting

```
            source  "/tmp/mob.tcl"
```

IHTH

Comment: i tried again but it give me this :

can't read "node_(0)": no such variable
    while executing
"$node_(0) set X_ 232.673397845604"
    (file "/tmp/mob.tcl" line 4)
    invoked from within
"source.orig /tmp/mob.tcl"
    ("uplevel" body line 1)
    invoked from within
"uplevel source.orig [list $fileName]"
    invoked from within
"if [$instance_ is_http_url $fileName] {
set buffer [$instance_ read_url $fileName]
uplevel eval $buffer
} else {
uplevel source.orig [list $fileName]
..."
    (procedure "source" line 8)
    invoked from within
"source  "/tmp/mob.tcl" "

Comment: @user3821478 Don't edit this question to add a new, unrelated error message. _Ask a new question._ We're not about to run out of IDs…

Comment: @DonalFellows, yes you're right. AT user3821478 , when you create a new quetsion for this, please paste in the error message. Use the `{}` tool at the top left of edit-box on the hightlighted text of your error messages to keep the formatting.  And please don't post with a  `bash` tag. Use `tcl` tag to help focus users with `tcl` experience to your problem. Good luck!