# IF and ! = ns2 error

Tags: tcl, ns2

I have a problem with path in a tcl file. I tried to use

```
source  " /tmp/mob.tcl "
```

and this path in bash file :

`/opt/ns-allinone-2.35/ns-2.35/indep-utils/cmu-scen-gen/setdest/setdest -v 1 -n $n -p 10 -M 64 -t 100 -x 250 -y 250 >> /tmp/mob.tcl`

The terminal give me this output:

```
    ..."
    (procedure "source" line 8)
    invoked from within
"source  "/tmp/mob.tcl" "
    (file "mobilita_source.tcl" line 125)
```

How I can do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Path Tcl and Bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24659881/path-tcl-and-bash)

Answer (score 2):

**Firstly,** this:

```
source  " /tmp/mob.tcl "
```

is very unlikely to be correct. The spaces around the filename *inside the quotes* will confuse the `source` command. (It could be correct, but only if you have a directory in your current directory whose name is a single space. That's really unlikely, unless you're a great deal more evil than I am.)

It really helps a lot if you stop making this error.

**Secondly,** the error message is both

- Incomplete, with just an ellipsis instead of a full error on the first line
- Really worrying, with `source` claimed to be a procedure (second line of that short trace).

It's *legal* to make a procedure called `source`, and sometimes the right thing to do, but if you're doing it then you have to be ever so careful to duplicate the semantics of the standard Tcl command or odd things will happen.

**Thirdly,** you've got a file of what is apparently generated code, and you're hitting a problem in it, and you're not telling us what is on/around line 125 of the file (the error trace is pretty clear on that front) or in the contents of the `source` procedure (which is non-standard; the standard `source` is implemented in C) and you're expecting us to guess what's going wrong for you??? Seriously?

---

Tcl error traces are usually quite clear enough for you to figure out what went wrong and where. If there's an unclear error, and it didn't come from user code (by calling `error` or `return -code error`) then let us know; we'll help (or possibly even change Tcl to make things clearer in the future). But right now, there's a complete shortage of information.

Here's an example of what a normal `source` error looks like:

```
% source /tmp/foo/bar/boo
couldn't read file "/tmp/foo/bar/boo": no such file or directory
% puts $errorInfo
couldn't read file "/tmp/foo/bar/boo": no such file or directory
    while executing
"source /tmp/foo/bar/boo"
```

If a script generates an error directly, it's encouraged to be as clear as that, but we cannot enforce it. Sometimes you have to be a bit of a detective yourself…